# pyaiml21 loadBrain method from Kernel not working

Tags: python, aiml

using Python 3.8.10 on Linux Mint

I have stripped my aiml down to a minimal version to test with but the `loadBrain` method does not sucessfully load the brain saved.

here is the aiml code, as 'q.aiml'

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <aiml>
        <category>
            <pattern>*</pattern>
            <template>test successful</template>
        </category>
    </aiml>
```

and here is the python, hugely simple

```
    from pyaiml21 import Kernel
    k=Kernel()
    # k.loadBrain('q.brn')
    k.learn('q.aiml')
    while True:
        a=input('>')
        if a == 'quit':
            break
        else:
            print (k.respond(a,'luke'))
    k.saveBrain('q.brn')
```

you can see that I run it using the `learn` method the first time. Then on the next run I comment that out and uncomment the `loadBrain` line. No joy.

I just get

```
    >test
    unknown
```

as output, when I am expecting 'test successful' obviously. Note that the `saveBrain` method does save a non-empty file. Can I assume it is `loadBrain` that is broken??

Answer (score 0):

The prolog `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is unnecessary and is the culprit of your question. Just delete it and try again.